# How to use visual studio code (MSVC) to compile multi-cpp file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cl, cl.exe

I have followed some instructions to construct Visual studio code C/C++ compile and debug environment. But MSVC compiler can only compile the selected cpp file, so the included .h file associated the cpp file can not compiled. then the terminal shows
*

> main.obj : LNK2019 error: reference to an unresolved external
> character "int __cdecl func(void)" (?func@@YAHXZ) in the main
> function.C:\TESTmsvc\main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: unresolved
> external elements: 1

### The code as below:

## the a.h file

```
int func();
```

## the a.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
using namespace std;
int func(){
return 111;
}
```

## the main.cpp file

#include "a.h"

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int b = func();
cout << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: use a build tool: Make, CMake, MSBuild,...

Comment: The VSCode documentation for msvc tells you here about the default behavior of only compiling the active file and how to modify that default to build all of your files: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_modifying-tasksjson)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use **CMake** for larger C++ and C projects.
When using VS Code you should

- download the extensions *CMake* and *CMake Tools* by Microsoft.
- create a *CMakeLists.txt* file in your project directory and (for a simple project) enter this code into your *CMakeLists.txt* file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(PROJECT_NAME)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(PROJECT_NAME
# add the files that need to be compiled here
src/main.cc
)
```

- Press **[ctrl + s]** to save the file and select a build kit. For a 64x build target on a 64x computer you should select:

  `Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - amd64`

With CMake you can also choose if you want to compile for Release, Debug, MinSizeRel or RelWithDebInfo. To do so, press **[crtl + shift + p]** to open the command pallete and type in *CMake: Select Variant*
For *Debug* you might want to select the *Debug* build target and click the debug button in the status bar.
For *Release* select the *Release* build target and click the run button.
VS Code debugging should work automatically when compiling for debug with the debug build target.

If you really want to use VS Code's build system with a *task.json* you can add the following line of code to the *task.json* to it:
`"${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp"`
This piece of code basically replaces the command to compile *main.cpp* with the command to compile *every .cpp* file found in the src directory

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question but instead presents an alternative.